# How to push this command in to history?

Tags: commands, history

I have this function in config

```
(defun launch-separate-emacs-under-x ()
  (interactive)
  (call-process "sh" nil nil nil "-c" "emacs &"))

(defun restart-emacs ()
  (interactive)
  (add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook
            (if (display-graphic-p)
                #'launch-separate-emacs-under-x
              #'launch-separate-emacs-in-terminal)
            t)
  (kill-emacs))
```

**Update:**

In general if i execute any command say `package-install` it will be added to command history. But when I execute above function using `M-x`, it is not getting added into commands history. How to make emacs to add this command to history?

Comment: If you execute that command via `helm-M-x`, I guess setting `helm-M-x-always-save-history` to t can save that history.

Comment: Looks like it is not working.

Comment: I can't try this command since I don't know `launch-separate-emacs-*`. And you didn't say where you invoke this command from, I should just assume the built-in `M-x`.  Does other commands works as you expected?  AFAIK , `extended-command-history` is usually used to keep command history and the `savehist` package can save various minibuffer input history across Emacs session.

Comment: @Name Sorry. I want emacs to remember that I have executed the that function. Update question

Comment: My guess is that it only gets added to history after it's done running but since emacs is getting killed that never happens. Instead of calling `kill-emacs` directly. Run `kill-emacs` on a 0 second timer so that the stack can clear and the command might then be added to the history.

Comment: If you know how command history works in your case, you can do it yourself, for example, at the beginning of the command `restart-emacs`, push the command to history variable and save related history file, then do some real stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command won't be placed into your command history until after it is run, and since the command kills emacs, that never happens.

You can counter this by killing emacs only after the command has ran and the call stack clears by running `kill-emacs` on a 0 second timer.

The call to `(kill-emacs)` would then be replaced with this:

```lisp
(run-with-timer 0 nil (lambda () (kill-emacs)))
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution is to move `kill-emacs` to seperate function.

```
(defun stop-emacs ()
  (kill-emacs))

(defun restart-emacs ()
  (interactive)
  (add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook
            (if (display-graphic-p)
                #'launch-separate-emacs-under-x
              #'launch-separate-emacs-in-terminal)
            t)
  (stop-emacs))
```